# Python tkinter checkbox does not work as expected when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I've just encountered an interesting problem with the tkinter widget checkbox and hoped that maybe someone could explain to me what exactly is happening here.

So, I am using a checkbox while also using a matplotlib figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Graph")
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)  


        self.sfnflag = tk.IntVar()

        self.c1 = tk.Checkbutton(master = self.root, text="Save Data from now on",
                            command=self.save_from_now, variable = self.sfnflag)
        self.c1.grid(column=1, row=3)

        self.root.update()

    def save_from_now(self):
        print(self.sfnflag.get())
GUI()
```

Checking and unchecking the checkbox always prints zero. However, if I call tk.Tk() before plt.figure(),the checkbox works as expected, giving alternating 1's and 0's.

While searching for the cause of this problem, I've seen similar cases when people used multiple instances of Tk(). I'm vaguely aware that matplotlib is also using tkinter, so I guess creating a matplotlib figure also calls on Tk() or something?

Comment: Each instance of `Tk()` is an entirely separate Tcl/Tk environment, each with its own set of variables/images/widgets/etc., that cannot interact with each other.  The specific problem here is that `self.sfnflag` is created in the first `Tk` by default (the one that matplotlib created), and therefore cannot be used with your Checkbutton that lives in the `Tk` you created.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the quick answer!